# How to evict invalid channel from FixedChannelPool?

Tags: netty

I'm using the built-in `FixedChannelPool` as my connection pool for netty http client. I have to remove the channel which is closed by remote server instead of returning this invalid channel back to the pool.

Unfortunately I didn't find the 'evict' API from the `ChannelPool` interface. So is there a way to get this job done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FixedChannelPool` has no feature like 'evict'. I've changed to use Apache Object Pool instead, and it works well.